# CS1936 C# Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'Student'. 'Where' not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
 private void DrawChart()
    {
        chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.Clear();


        var Student_A = from s in Student
                        where ((s.CW1 * 0.3) + (s.CW2 * 0.3) + (s.Exam * 0.4)) >= 70
                        where ((s.CW1 * 0.3) + (s.CW2 * 0.3) + (s.Exam * 0.4)) <= 100
                        select s;

        listBox1.Items[0] = "A" + GetStars(Student_A.Tolist().Count);
        chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.Add(1).Label = Student_A.ToList().Count.ToString();
        chart1.Series["Series1"].Points[0].LegendText = "A";
     }
```

CS1936 C# Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'Student'. 'Where' not found.

Getting this error while trying to add data to a pie chart, I have included `using System.Linq;` 
Student is an object
but there is also an array called StudentList where the students are saved to be shown and stored in a datatable, thanks.

Comment: Student (just from the name) seems like it should be a single object, and not something you should be able to enumerate. I'd think you'd run that against a StudentList. But, without knowing the types, who can say. See [mcve].

Comment: It gives me an error telling me that it is unable to accept an array. Student Is a single objective, is there anything else I can show you to make this more clear, thanks.

Comment: as the MCVE link says, a minimal program that we can run if need-be to see the error.  But, I'd guess if you want a single student, you'd want to get it from a list of students, and so you'd run that query against the list

Answer (score -1):

From [a quick google search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1936) of that error code, that error occurs when you try to run a query against a single object.

If `Student` is a single object, rather than a collection, that's your error.

It should look like the following:

```
class Student { ... }
List<Student> StudentList = new List<Student>();

Student A = from s in StudentList ....

//do stuff with A
```

EDIT: [Google again](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1934) . MS' compiler errors, are, in general, very googleable.

```
Student A = from Student s in Student List ....
```

Comment: ArrayList StudentList = new ArrayList();
My array list defined

The error i'm getting from trying StudentList instead of student.

CS1934  C# Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'ArrayList'.  'Where' not found.  Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 's'.

Thanks

Comment: Do not use `ArrayList`. It's pretty far out of date and LINQ won't work with it. Use `List<Student>` as shown in Phil's example.